# How to scrape data in HTML file from a certain line onwards

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape data from an HTML file. it looks like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import urllib
redditPage1 = "http://redditlist.com/sfw"
r=urllib.urlopen(redditPage1).read()
soup = bs(r)
```

Now I want to get the reddit moderators (or subredditors, as they are called) in a list by order of the number of their subscribers. For that I need to only look at the data that comes after the this line of code:

```
<h3 class="listing-header">Subscribers</h3>
```

Everything before this line is irrelevant and all entries about the subredditors after this line look like this:

```
<div class="listing-item" data-target-filter="sfw" data-target-subreddit="funny">
<div class="offset-anchor" id="funny-subscribers"></div>
<span class="rank-value">1</span>
<span class="subreddit-info-panel-toggle sfw"> <div>i</div> </span>
<span class="subreddit-url">
<a class="sfw" href="http://reddit.com/r/funny" target="_blank">funny</a>
</span>
<span class="listing-stat">18,197,786</span>
</div>
```

What should I do to be able to extract the subredditor names that come after this line and not before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to find the `<h3 class="listing-header">Subscribers</h3>`, then get the parent `div`, the scope will be limited to `Subscribers` div. Then find all div whose class is `listing-item`, loop them to get the text (names) of inside element `<a>`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import urllib
redditPage1 = "http://redditlist.com/sfw"
r=urllib.urlopen(redditPage1).read()
soup = bs(r,'lxml')
for sub_div in soup.find("h3", text="Subscribers").parent.find_all('div',{ "class" : "listing-item" }):
    print(sub_div.find('a').getText())
```

Comment: Oh one more question. Say, I want to read  not only redditpage1 but also redditpage2 and redditpage3. Is it possible to do that with a single soup? or shoud i loop through each one of them?

Comment: you need to loop through each page (`http://redditlist.com/sfw?page=2`) with passing the page number.

Answer (score 1):

To get the desired results making your code much readable, you can go like this as well.

```
import requests
from lxml.html import fromstring

res = requests.get("http://redditlist.com/sfw").text
root = fromstring(res)
for container in root.cssselect(".listing"):
    if container.cssselect("h3:contains('Subscribers')"):
        for subreddit in container.cssselect(".listing-item"):
            print(subreddit.attrib['data-target-subreddit'])
```

Or with `BeautifulSoup` if you like:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

main_link = "http://redditlist.com/all?page={}"
for link in [main_link.format(page) for page in range(1,5)]:
    res = requests.get(link).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res,"lxml")
    for container in soup.select(".listing"):
        if container.select("h3")[0].text=="Subscribers":
            for subreddit in container.select(".listing-item"):
                print(subreddit['data-target-subreddit'])
```

Comment: Your code prints ALL the `data-target-subreddit` texts in the html file, whereas I'm only interested in those coming after `<h3 class="listing-header">Subscribers</h3>` in that file. I don't know how your answer helps me.

Comment: My bad!! I missed that line. Will update the answer soon.

Comment: Now, check it out.

Comment: hmm interesting. I'm learning beautifulsoup, so i would prefer a solution utilising that. but your solution seems to work just  as fine! thanks for the alternative.

Comment: Added coding with `BeautifulSoup` as well. I found it interesting that is why I did. Thanks.

Comment: oh nice! though i feel like there is a bug in  your code. when i take it and instead of printing the output append it to a list, after the loop i expect a list that has 125 elements. but your code produces a dynamic list, that , after each execution of the code, grows almost exponentially duplicating the elements of the initial 125 strong list. trying to see, where that is coming from.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157182/discussion-between-artre-and-shahin).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for div in soup.select('.span4.listing'):
    if div.h3.text.lower()=='subscribers':
        output = [(ss.select('a.sfw')[0].text, ss.select('.listing-stat')[0].text) for ss in div.select('.listing-item')]
```

Comment: thx!that seems to work as well. But when i print out the list of texts, it looks like this `u'text'`. why is there a `u` there and how can i get rid of it?